# android google maps animate the camera slowly to my location

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to move the camera to my location slowly in android, i use the code below but the camera change from position to another like switching between pages. this is my code

```
                 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(location1)
                            .zoom(16)
                            .bearing(90)
                            .tilt(30)
                            .build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 10000, null);

                    CameraUpdate center=
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location1);
                 //   CameraUpdate zoomcam=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom);

                    googleMap.moveCamera(center);
```

Comment: why are you moving camera for the second time? the line `googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 10000, null);` should already move the camera to the desired location. Did you try removing the code where you try to move the google map camera for the second time?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the CameraUpdateAnimator from my MapUtils project here: https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `googleMap.moveCamera(center);`.
Use only `googleMap.animateCamera(center);`.